# How to make pagination with first page and last page Django

Tags: django, templates, pagination

I have some code with template helpers bcs im using django-filter but it doesn`t rly matter

I want to make better pagination in my template with first and  last page and with '...' when you`re going trough pagination

How can i do this?

template.html

```
{% load templatehelpers %}
{% if page_obj.has_other_pages %}
    <nav aria-label="paginator">
        <ul class="pagination">

            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <li class="page-item ">
                    <a class="page-link"
                       href="{% relative_url page_obj.previous_page_number 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}">
                        <i class="bi bi-arrow-left"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link">
                        <i class="bi bi-arrow-left"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}

            {% for i in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                {% if page_obj.number == i %}
                    <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
                        <a class="page-link" href="{% relative_url i 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}">{{ i }}</a>
                    </li>
                {% elif i > page_obj.number|add:-3 and i < page_obj.number|add:3 %}
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="{% relative_url i 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}">{{ i }}</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}


            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link"
                       href="{% relative_url page_obj.next_page_number 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}">
                        <i class="bi bi-arrow-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">
                        <i class="bi bi-arrow-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}

        </ul>
    </nav>
{% endif %}
```

I want something like that:

[image: I want something like that]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django Paginator has a convenient method `get_elided_page_range` which you can use to get a cool looking pagination:

```py
{% load templatehelpers %}
{% if page_obj.has_other_pages %}
    <nav aria-label="paginator">
        <ul class="pagination">

            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <li class="page-item ">
                    <a class="page-link"
                       href="{% relative_url page_obj.previous_page_number 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}">
                        <i class="bi bi-arrow-left"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link">
                        <i class="bi bi-arrow-left"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}

            {# For a small number of pages, just render them all (without ellipsis elements) #}
            {% if paginator.num_pages < 10 %}
                {% for i in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                    {% if page_obj.number == i %}
                        <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
                            <a class="page-link" href="{% relative_url i 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}">{{ i }}</a>
                        </li>
                    {% elif i > page_obj.number|add:-3 and i < page_obj.number|add:3 %}
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link" href="{% relative_url i 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}">{{ i }}</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}

                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                 {% for page_number in paginator|elided_page_range:page_obj.number %}
                    {% if page_number == page_obj.number %}
                        {# This is the current page #}
                        <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
                            <a class="page-link" href="{% relative_url i 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}">{{ page_number }}</a>
                        </li>

                    {% elif page_number == paginator.ELLIPSIS %}
                        {# I handle this case cause you probably want to specially display the ellipsis. Maybe disable the link? #}
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link" href="{% relative_url i 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}">{{ page_number }}</a>
                        </li>

                    {% else %}
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a class="page-link" href="{% relative_url i 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}">{{ page_number }}</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}


            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link"
                       href="{% relative_url page_obj.next_page_number 'page' request.GET.urlencode %}">
                        <i class="bi bi-arrow-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% else %}
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#">
                        <i class="bi bi-arrow-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}

        </ul>
    </nav>
{% endif %}
```

You must be wondering about the `elided_page_range` filter. That's a custom filter that is necessary to implement since you can't pass arguments when calling functions from Django templates.

Here's the implementation:

```py
@register.filter
def elided_page_range(paginator, number):
    return paginator.get_elided_page_range(number)
```